# Is there away to avoid the printing the same element into the array

Tags: java, arrays

I've tried creating many variations, I tried switching the nested for loops and I tried storing it in a temp value but to know avail, this is a test code of my original code that will invoke multiple methods and I dont want it to get overwritten

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] memoryArray = new char[24];
        String s = new String("hello");
        int start = 0;
        int length = s.length();
        String d = new String("world");
        int length1 = d.length();
        char tmp;
        for (int i = start; i < length - start; i++) {
            if (memoryArray[i] == '\u0000') {
                memoryArray[i] = s.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        start = start + length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
            tmp = d.charAt(i);
            for (int j = start; j < start + length1; j++)
                if (memoryArray[j] == '\u0000') {
                    memoryArray[j] = tmp;
                }
        }
        System.out.println(memoryArray);
    }
}
```

expected output helloworld

Comment: Javascript is not Java.

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag removed and code formatted for readability

Comment: Aside: `memoryArray[i] == '\u0000'` is the same as `memoryArray[i] == '\0'`, and also the same as `memoryArray[i] == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you know what the two strings are, `hello` and `world`, but what if you didn't know what strings those variables will hold?

The easiest solution to create the array would be to:

1. Concatenate the strings together into a new String variable;
2. Declare the `memoryArray` and place each character within the new concatenated string into that array;
3. Display the contents of `memoryArray`.

With this in mind:

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "programming";
String c = "world";

// Concatenate the strings together
String newString = new StringBuilder(a).append(b).append(c).toString();

// Declare memoryArray and fill with the characters from newString.
char[] memoryArray = newString.toCharArray();

// Display the Array contents
System.out.println(memoryArray);
```

But if you want to utilize a `for` loop for this sort of thing then these steps can do the trick:

1. Concatenate the strings together into a `newString` String variable;
2. Declare the `memoryArray` and initialize it based on the `newString` length;
3. Create a `for` loop to iterate through the `newString` **one** character at a time;
4. Within the loop, add each character to the `memoryArray` character array;
5. Display the contents of `memoryArray`.

With this in mind:

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "programming";
String c = "world";

// Concatenate the strings together
String newString = new StringBuilder(a).append(b).append(c).toString();

// Declare and initialize the memoryArray array based on the length of newString.
char[] memoryArray = new char[newString.length()];

// Iterate through newString and fill memoryArray
for (int i = 0; i < newString.length(); i++) {
    memoryArray[i] = newString.charAt(i);
}

// Display the Array contents
System.out.println(memoryArray);
```